# Get Employee who haven't mark attendance for continuous 11 days

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the employee from database who haven't mark attendance for continuous 11 days
for that I have Employee Table and Attendance Table, but the problem I am facing in this that I don't have record in the attendance table, so how can I get that

I have tried many queries some of them are

```
SELECT e.name, e.full_name
FROM tabEmployee e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        employee,
        MIN(attendance_date) AS first_attendance_date
    FROM tabAttendance
    GROUP BY employee
) ar ON e.name = ar.employee
WHERE ar.first_attendance_date IS NULL OR 
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM tabAttendance
          WHERE employee = e.name
          AND attendance_date >= ar.first_attendance_date
          AND attendance_date < DATE_ADD(ar.first_attendance_date, INTERVAL 11 DAY)
      )
```

another query

```
SELECT e.name, COUNT(a.`attendance_date`), COUNT(e.`name`) from tabEmployee e
LEFT JOIN tabAttendance a ON e.name = a.`employee`
WHERE a.`employee` IS NULL
GROUP BY e.`name`
```

Comment: 11 past days from today, or any continuous run of 11 days?

Comment: Any continuous 11 days @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Which column(s) indicate absence or attendance?

Comment: status column in tabAttendance table @TimBiegeleisen , but the problem is if Employee haven't marked attendance then I don't have record in attendance table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `LAG()` analytic function, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.name, e.full_name,
           LAG(a.attendance_date) OVER (PARTITION BY a.employee
                                        ORDER BY a.attendance_date) AS lag_attendance_date
    FROM tabAttendance a
    INNER JOIN tabEmployee e ON e.name = a.employee
)

SELECT DISTINCT name, full_name
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF(attendance_date, lag_attendance_date) > 11;
```

The basic strategy here is to generate the lag (previous sequential value) of the attendance date in the CTE.  We then report only employees having a gap of 11 or more days.

Comment: thanks, worked for me with little modification as per my table columns :)